# Extracing value from json using json path

Tags: json, path, expression, jsonpath

I've tried to extract the id value based on email value from the following json:

```
[
{"id":11,"username":"John","address":"London","email":"john@test.com"},
{"id":12,"username":"Piere","address":"Paris","email":"piere@test.com"},
{"id":13,"username":"Anne","address":"Moscow","email":"anne@test.com"},
]
```

My expression is

```
$..[?(@.email=='anne@test.com')].id
```

It doesn't work. What is wrong with this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is correct. I think you need to correct your JSON data instead. There is a syntax error.
This is the correct one:

```
[
{"id":11,"username":"John","address":"London","email":"john@test.com"},
{"id":12,"username":"Piere","address":"Paris","email":"piere@test.com"},
{"id":13,"username":"Anne","address":"Moscow","email":"anne@test.com"}
]
```

You can use this to validate your JSON first next time.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

You may also validate your expression here

http://jsonpath.com/

[image: Json validator]